# using php to enter data into mysql database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm currently trying to enter data from a form in a wordpress web page into a mysql database.

here is the code from the html page on wordpress

```
<table>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="basisForm.php">
<strong>Please enter your information in order to download the Macs Cabs App</strong>
<tr><td>
Surmane Name:</td><td><input name="sname" type="text" id="sname"></td></tr> 
<tr><td>
First Name:</td><td><input name="fname" type="text" id="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Home Address:</td><td><input name="homeaddr" type="text" id="homeaddr"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Most common Destination:</td><td><input name="commondest" type="text" id="commondest"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Mobile Number:</td><td><input name="mobileno" type="text" id="mobileno"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Home Number:</td><td><input name="homeno" type="text" id="homeno"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Email Address:</td><td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

 mysql_select_db("macs cabs", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO customers (sname, fname, homeaddr, commondest, mobileno, homeno, email)
VALUES
  ('$_POST[sname]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[homeaddr]','$_POST[commondest]','$_POST[mobileno]','$_POST[     homeno]','$_POST[email]')";          




if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 echo "1 record added";

 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

i have installed the phpexec plugin and that seems to be runing fine.

when i enter data in the form and i submit it doesnt appear in the database.

My primary key seems to auto increment telling me something happened but no data appears.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using mysql_* functions. Your insert query doesn't escapes the user inputs. And is likely lead to sql injections

Use PDO or mysqli instead. Both allows prepared statements.

`$_POST` is an associative array. So, you will be passing the key to get a particular value.
For example, if the POST array contain a key named "name", then you can access it like this: `$_POST['name']`. You can use either single/double quotes.

A good tutorial for learning PDO: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO customers (sname, fname, homeaddr, commondest, mobileno, homeno, email)
VALUES  ('{$_POST['sname']}','{$_POST['fname']}','{$_POST['homeaddr']}','{$_POST['commondest']}','{$_POST['mobileno']}','{$_POST['homeno']}','{$_POST['email']}')";
```

Also, I assume you understand the risks of SQL injections into your database. i.e. you should never insert user entered data straight into your database, you should do some sort of sanitization beforehand.

Comment: i tried this jamalali, again the primary key is auto incrementing but the data is not going in. thanks for the tip on the sanitization, i will carry this out once i figure out this problem

Comment: Ok. Are you getting any error messages at all? Put this before you close the database connection and see what info you get back:

`$info = mysql_info();
echo $info;`

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,,,)' at line 2

Comment: Ok, so that suggests their are no values being added into your sql statement. As a test, hand code the values and see if that inserts anything into the database.

Comment: @Dalyn I'm fairly sure string values in an sql INSERT statement need to be quoted.

Comment: the test works jamalali, when i insert the data in by hand it works

Comment: this is my new error after i have changed the syntax mysql_error(): 20 is not a valid MySQL-Link

Comment: Ok, so now you know it's the way you're posting from the form to your PHP. Get to know how to do this on a standalone test site first before integrating it into wordpress. What syntax did you change?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the answer you were looking for but...

I would probably use wordpress built in functions for this. Custom post types allow this functionality. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) There is a article here about it:http://wpshout.com/wordpress-submit-posts-from-frontend/

This means you leverage wordpress's input santizing and allows a ui to view the data in the backend to edit and delete etc.

Answer (score 0):

@jamalali81 is on the right track with his answer but I would remove the '' around the $_POST variables so the code would look like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO customers (sname, fname, homeaddr, commondest, mobileno, homeno, email)
VALUES ({$_POST['sname']},{$_POST['fname']},{$_POST['homeaddr']},{$_POST['commondest']},{$_POST['mobileno']},{$_POST['homeno']},{$_POST['email']})";
```

You should also be using PDO and cleaning the variables to avoid SQL injection.

A customers table structure would also be helpful if the above doesn't resolve your issue.

Comment: custno int(11) NO PRI NULL auto_increment 
      sname varchar(15) NO MUL NULL   
      fname varchar(15) NO   NULL   
      homeaddr varchar(15) NO   NULL   
      commondest varchar(50) NO   NULL   
      mobileno varchar(15) NO   NULL   
      homeno varchar(15) NO   NULL   
      email int(50) NO   NULL

Comment: Thank you but please put your table structure in your original question in the code format and include the exact code from the database, not abbreviations.

Answer (score -1):

check with this query:-

```
"INSERT INTO customers (sname, fname, homeaddr, commondest, mobileno, homeno, email)
VALUES
  ('$_POST['sname']','$_POST['fname']','$_POST['homeaddr']','$_POST['commondest']','$_POST['mobileno']','$_POST['homeno']','$_POST['email']')";
```

may helpful...:)